# 7zip will only zip up certain files

Tags: command-line, zip, 7-zip, vbscript

I have a script for zipping up old files and deleting them. The script works fine in all other directories but one specific directory will not work. It will attempt to zip it up but end up only creating an empty zip file called `Program.7z`. This makes me think that the spaces are not being escaped properly in the script. I used double and single quotes in my paths and check the concatenation of the file paths. I haven't found what it could be. Any ideas?

```
Const fileZillaLogs = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Server\Logs"
Const zipProgram = """C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe"""
Const zipArgs = "a -mx9"
Dim intZipAge
intZipAge = 7
Dim intDelAge
intDelAge = 90


Call DeleteLogFiles(fileZillaLogs, intZipAge, intDelAge)



Function DeleteLogFiles(strLogPath, intZipAge, intDelAge)
  Const bDEBUG = True
  Dim objFs
  Dim objFolder
  Dim objSubFolder
  Dim objFile
  Dim objWShell
  Dim strCommand
  Dim iResult
  Set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If Right(strLogPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    strLogPath = strLogPath & "\"
  End If
  If objFs.FolderExists(strLogPath) Then
    Set objFolder = objFs.GetFolder(strLogPath)
      For Each objSubFolder in objFolder.subFolders
        DeleteLogFiles strLogPath & objSubFolder.Name, intZipAge, intDelAge
      Next
      For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
        If bDebug Then wscript.echo vbTab & "reviewing file = " & strLogPath & objFile.Name
        If DateDiff("d",objFile.DateLastModified,Date) > intDelAge Then
          If bDebug Then wscript.echo "Deleting because its old" End If
          objFs.DeleteFile(strLogPath & objFile.Name)
        Else If DateDiff("d",objFile.DateLastModified,Date) > intZipAge _
          And (Right(objFile.Name, 4) = ".log") Then
            If bDebug Then wscript.echo vbTab & "zipping file = " & objFile.Path
            strCommand = zipProgram & " " & zipArgs & " " & objFile.Path & ".7z" & " " & objFile.Path
            iResult = objWShell.Run(strCommand, 0, "false")
            If bDebug Then wscript.echo vbTab & "zipping result = " & iResult
            If bDebug Then wscript.echo vbTab & "deleting file = " & strLogPath & objFile.Name
            objFs.DeleteFile(strLogPath & objFile.Name)
            End If
        End If
      Next
    Set objFs = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objWShell = nothing
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the directory name that fails, and the names of the failing files? Also are the permissions set differently for that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on line 41. Your *objFile.Path* has spaces in it but your adding it to a command line argument. This means that the spaces should be encapsulated in quotes, but you can't use quotes since they are used to concatenate the string. You must then escape the quotes that should be in the end result string. In VBS the escape character is the double quote character. So your line 41 should look like this:

```
strCommand = zipProgram & " " & zipArgs & " " & """" & objFile.Path & ".7z" & """" & " " & """" & objFile.Path & """"
```

Notice the """" sequences, which are basically calculated as such:

- First double quote: beginning of string
- Second double quote: escapes the next character
- Third double quote: is the character you want in your final string
- Fourth double quote: end of string

I tested it out and it works fine. You have to escape both time that you use the *objFile.Path* function.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now